# Parametrize insert Python pymysql

Tags: python, pymysql

I have the following block of code

```
def write_metadata(self):
    try:
        with self.sql_writer.cursor as cursor:
            for data in self.input_data:
                sql = ("""INSERT INTO Sample (SampleName, TransferStatus, ClientSid, ClientSubjectId, ClientName, ProjectId, ProjectName, ExecutionId, Deleted)
                    VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s""")
                package_data = (data.sample_name, 0, 'client_sid', "Testing", data.client_name, data.project_id, data.project_name, '12345', '0')
                cursor.execute(sql, package_data)
            self.sql_writer.conn.commit()
    finally:
       self.sql_writer.conn.close()
```

the error that I am getting is

```
"errorMessage": "(1064, u\"You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1\")"
```

Is there an issue with my parametrize  of the sql?
Is the issue because some of the values are numbers and %s is for string?
Is the issue because some of the values are None?

Thanks.

Comment: Testing now @roganjosh. Thank you.

Comment: ```ProgrammingError: (1064, u"You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 2"```

Comment: You are missing a closing brace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a close paren `)` at the end of your `VALUES()`.

You are also using a multi-line string incorrectly. Try this:

```
sql = """INSERT INTO Sample (SampleName, TransferStatus, ClientSid, ClientSubjectId, ClientName, ProjectId, ProjectName, ExecutionId, Deleted)
          VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)"""
```

Comment: Thank you fixing the multi-string and adding the closing paren has resolved the issue.